# Object can not be deleted is attribute is active - Rspec RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test if object is active and it is active then it can not be deleted. So for i have this in my plan_spec.rb:

```
  it "can not be deleted if active" do
    plan = Plan.new(active: true)
    r = plan.destroy
    r.should_not be_valid
  end
```

Name of the attribute i'm trying to check is 'active' and it is boolean, so if active is true then it can't object plan can not be deleted.
Any help?

Comment: Did any of the ansers help you?

Comment: I'm trying to test everything, although i'm getting error with this line: expect { plan.destroy }.to_not change(Plan.count) . Error is: TypeError: nil is not a symbol. Thanks for help anyways

Comment: It may be because of my mistake - try this: `expect { plan.destroy }.to_not change { Plan.count }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by using `before_destroy` callback which will return `false` if record can't be destroyed:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  before_destroy :check_if_active
  # ...
  private

  def check_if_active
    !active?
  end
end
```

With this solution, you should also rewrite your test, cause you shouldn't check validity:

```
it 'can not be deleted if active' do
  plan = Plan.create!(active: true)
  expect { plan.destroy }.to_not change { Plan.count }
end
```

Comment: in `Rspec` better to use `expect { ...  }.to change { ..... }` . `assert_no_difference` is a minitest  `ActiveSupport::Testing::Assertions`.

Comment: @Зелёный You're right, thanks. As you see, I'm used to minitest.

Answer (score 1):

in your `Plan` class, add:

```
before_destroy :ensure_inactive

#will abort destroy if return false
def ensure_inactive
  !active?
end
```

Btw, your spec is wrong, its not really a validation. You should:

- save the object
- call destroy
- ensure it has not been destroyed

Comment: You read my mind, we created two independent but practically identical answers. :)

Comment: I do have callbacks but i'm trying to write Rspec test

Comment: @MilanČančarević this answer covers modification of spec code too.

Comment: As you said, save the object, call destroy, ensure it has not been destroyed how can i do that? Callbacks are working fine but i'm trying to write rspec test. Sorry i'm new to RoR still

Comment: @MilanČančarević look at my answer for ready to use (at least I think so) code.